# How to interpret the coefficients of polynomial predictors of logistic regression (summary in R)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I'm performing a logistic regression using polynomial predictior for the first time. I would like to have an explanation on how to intepret the polynomial coefficient of this logistic regression:

Context: the target variable (presence) is a dichotomous variable that can be thought as suitable/unsuitable.

Here's the summary:

```
Call:
glm(formula = presence ~ poly(bio3, 2) + poly(bio8, 2) + poly(bio9, 
    2) + poly(bio14, 2) + poly(bio15, 2) + poly(bio18, 2), family = "binomial", 
    data = data, weights = weights)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-5.0625  -0.7191  -0.4772  -0.1345   5.6488  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -1.9112     0.2603  -7.342 2.10e-13 ***
poly(bio3, 2)1     0.7902     4.6616   0.170 0.865401    
poly(bio3, 2)2    18.4565     5.2450   3.519 0.000433 ***
poly(bio8, 2)1  -108.8864    29.1761  -3.732 0.000190 ***
poly(bio8, 2)2   -33.3462    16.9549  -1.967 0.049211 *  
poly(bio9, 2)1   200.5550    21.8391   9.183  < 2e-16 ***
poly(bio9, 2)2   -78.6589    13.4128  -5.864 4.51e-09 ***
poly(bio14, 2)1  -23.8799     6.6029  -3.617 0.000299 ***
poly(bio14, 2)2   22.2871     7.3392   3.037 0.002392 ** 
poly(bio15, 2)1  -41.4126     6.0777  -6.814 9.50e-12 ***
poly(bio15, 2)2   -7.7564     4.1591  -1.865 0.062193 .  
poly(bio18, 2)1  -40.9162     4.8085  -8.509  < 2e-16 ***
poly(bio18, 2)2   28.9909     5.3227   5.447 5.13e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2262.4  on 1631  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1298.0  on 1619  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1893.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

I'll use the bio18 (last 2 lines of coefficients section) as an example. I interpret the estimate of `poly(bio18, 2)1` as it was bio18^1. So the negative estimate of this predictor (-40.91) tells me that on average the higher is the value of bio18 the more the target is "unsuitable" because it should be a linear relationship.

But how can I interpret the estimate of `poly(bio18, 2)2`? I'm very confuse about it. Of course I can't use the same reasoning.

Comment: It is much easier to understand the output of complex models if you *plot* them. The [ggeffects](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/#:~:text=ggeffects%20is%20a%20light%2Dweight,holds%20the%20non%2Dfocal%20variables) package is one tool that can help with this.

Comment: Also see the `rms` package `Predict` and `ggplot` functions.  Don't try to interpret individual coefficients at all.  Also create general contrasts (differences in predicted values).  Much more at https://hbiostat.org/bbrc .  **IMPORTANT**: what is the frequency count of `presence` and non-presence/

Comment: The count is non-presence=1484 presence =148, I also gave them the same weights and added the argument weights in the glm